# Enable "Rating setting" on List programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online

Iam trying to enable the Rating settings programmatically but it seems not working . Iam not getting any error but it dont update the list with new columns `LikeCount` and `LikedBy`. I dont want to use PnP samples . Here is my code:

```
 private void SetProperty(ClientContext ctx, string listname, VotingExperience experience)
    {
       Web rootWeb = ctx.Site.RootWeb;
       List list = rootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);

        try
        {
            list.Context.Load(list.RootFolder, p => p.Properties);
            list.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

       list.RootFolder.Properties["Ratings_VotingExperience"] = experience.ToString();
            list.RootFolder.Update();
            list.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

       }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

**Accessing :**

```
SetRating(ctx, Lists.title, VotingExperience.Likes);
```

Is it correct way of doing ?? Anyone has experienced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying with a invalid property name. Instead of `Ratings_VotingExperience` use `Ratings_x005f_VotingExperience`.

```
list.RootFolder.Properties["Ratings_x005f_VotingExperience"] = "Likes";
```

So question is: Where did I get that? In the following end-point:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Lists/{ListName}')/Properties
```

I have sent a GET request to the above `URL` and it returned me something like `Ratings_x005f_VotingExperience`.

## Update

It's true above thing does not work! So I had a little R&D and made it working. Basically we need to add two site columns in list to make **Rating thing** working. I got the idea from **Rating Settings** itself.

[image]

## Site columns are:

- `LikesCount` which GUID `ID` is `6e4d832b-f610-41a8-b3e0-239608efda41`
- `LikedBy` which GUID `ID` is `2cdcd5eb-846d-4f4d-9aaf-73e8e73c7312`

**PS:** These Guids are fixed

So I added these columns using below code and enabled **Rating Settings**

```
using(ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite)) {
    clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
    clientContext.Load(list);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var likeCount = web.AvailableFields.GetById(new Guid("6e4d832b-f610-41a8-b3e0-239608efda41"));
    var likedBy = web.AvailableFields.GetById(new Guid("2cdcd5eb-846d-4f4d-9aaf-73e8e73c7312"));

    clientContext.Load(likeCount, p => p.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens, p => p.Id, p => p.InternalName, p => p.StaticName);
    clientContext.Load(likedBy, p => p.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens, p => p.Id, p => p.InternalName, p => p.StaticName);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(likeCount.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint | AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
    list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(likedBy.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens, false, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint | AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);

    list.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Above code will enable like/unlike. For other things, we have enable those also. Find [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Core.ListRatingSettings/Core.ListRatingSettings/RatingsEnabler.cs)

```
private readonly Guid RatingsFieldGuid_AverageRating = new Guid("5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742");
private readonly Guid RatingsFieldGuid_RatingCount = new Guid("b1996002-9167-45e5-a4df-b2c41c6723c7");
private readonly Guid RatingsFieldGuid_RatedBy = new Guid("4D64B067-08C3-43DC-A87B-8B8E01673313");
private readonly Guid RatingsFieldGuid_Ratings = new Guid("434F51FB-FFD2-4A0E-A03B-CA3131AC67BA");
```

Comment: before enabling it has one more property  
Allow items in this list to be rated ? . can it be a problem ?? i dont know how to set true on that.

Comment: I guess, you should set `"Likes"` instead of `Boolean`

Comment: i have following                                                                                public enum VotingExperience
    {
        Ratings = 0,
        Likes = 1,
    }  ok let me try

Comment: So is it working now??

Comment: no still not working :( , trying since morning but still with no luck

Comment: Then I have to try!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35291/discussion-between-meer-and-atish-dipongkor).

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear-Host

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell | Out-Null

$ass = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal")  

$web = Get-SPWeb http://url
$lst = $web.Lists["list"]

$reputationHelper = $ass.GetTypes().Where({$_.Name -eq "ReputationHelper"})[0]
$enableReputation = $reputationHelper.GetMethod("EnableReputation", ([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic))
$enableReputation.Invoke($null, @($lst, "Likes", $false))
```

Comment: This will not work in SharePoint Online