# How to create Star Rating column in list programmatically using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, rating

Is it possible to create/enable rating column on a list using CSOM, as I tried but was unable to find any working code?

I was able to set the value to `AverageRating` column using JSOM. Is it possible using `AddFieldAsXml`?

**Exact issue:**

When creating a list there is a need to create columns dynamically using JSOM but I'm facing an issue while creating Star rating column.

I know it can be enabled in List Settings but is it possible to handle through code?

Comment: Check this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169130/enable-rating-setting-on-list-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PnP Sample to enable rating in your list.

```
var ratingEnabler = new RatingsEnabler(clientContext);

ratingEnabler.Enable("ListName", VotingExperience.Ratings);
```

The value can be set as `VotingExperience.Ratings` or `VotingExperience.Likes`

Reference - [Core.ListRatingSettings](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ListRatingSettings)

Or you can use the below code. Here , the GUID is hardcoded and they remain the same across the tenant:

```
public static void EnableRating()
{
 string siteUrl = "https://sitecollectionurl.sharepoint.com/sites/test";
 string userName = "user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com";
 string password = "password";
 string listTitle = "List";


 Guid RatingsFieldGuid_AverageRating = new Guid("5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742");
 Guid RatingsFieldGuid_RatingCount = new Guid("b1996002-9167-45e5-a4df-b2c41c6723c7");
 Guid RatingsFieldGuid_RatedBy = new Guid("4D64B067-08C3-43DC-A87B-8B8E01673313");
 Guid RatingsFieldGuid_Ratings = new Guid("434F51FB-FFD2-4A0E-A03B-CA3131AC67BA");
 Guid LikeFieldGuid_LikedBy = new Guid("2cdcd5eb-846d-4f4d-9aaf-73e8e73c7312");
 Guid LikeFieldGuid_LikeCount = new Guid("6e4d832b-f610-41a8-b3e0-239608efda41");

 using (var ctx = = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
 {
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

     ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     List filesLibrary = ctx.Web.GetListByTitle(listTitle);

     ctx.Load(filesLibrary);

     ctx.Load(filesLibrary);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     ctx.Load(filesLibrary.RootFolder, p => p.Properties);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     filesLibrary.RootFolder.Properties["Ratings_VotingExperience"] = "Likes";
     filesLibrary.RootFolder.Update();

     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     EnsureField(filesLibrary, RatingsFieldGuid_RatingCount, ctx);
     EnsureField(filesLibrary, RatingsFieldGuid_RatedBy, ctx);
     EnsureField(filesLibrary, RatingsFieldGuid_Ratings, ctx);
     EnsureField(filesLibrary, RatingsFieldGuid_AverageRating, ctx);
     EnsureField(filesLibrary, LikeFieldGuid_LikedBy, ctx);
     EnsureField(filesLibrary, LikeFieldGuid_LikeCount, ctx);

     filesLibrary.Update();
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     ctx.Load(filesLibrary, view => view.DefaultView);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     var defaultView = filesLibrary.DefaultView;
     defaultView.ViewFields.Add("LikesCount");

     defaultView.Update();
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 }
}

private static Field EnsureField(List list, Guid fieldId, ClientContext context)
{
 FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;

 FieldCollection availableFields = list.ParentWeb.AvailableFields;
 Field field = availableFields.GetById(fieldId);

 context.Load(fields);
 context.Load(field, p => p.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens, p => p.Id, p => p.InternalName, p => p.StaticName);
 context.ExecuteQuery();

 if (!fields.Any(p => p.Id == fieldId))
 {
     var newField = fields.AddFieldAsXml(field.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens, false, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint | AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
     return newField;
 }
 return field;
}
```

[Enable Ratings/Likes For A List In SharePoint Office 365 Programmatically Using C#](http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Enable-RatingsLikes-For-a-List-in-SharePoint-Office-365-Programmatically-using-PNP-C)

**Note** - in case there is some issue with rating not getting enabled, you can replace the property bag key as `Ratings_x005f_VotingExperience` and then check. See the link in the comments.

Comment: hi @vinodkumar , did you try the above code, is it working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Microsoft hasn't given any direct approach to enable ratings in a list using CSOM, as mentioned in the in the comments by Gautam Sheth, there might be some work around but I haven't tried it yet, so I'm not sure about it.